# MySQL is stripping em dash despite database and connection set to UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

So I've got users submitting a text field, and in this particular case it's not accepting em dash. Everything from em dash on is stripped out and only the preceding part of the string is inserted into the database.

The string is being posted fine, I've narrowed it down to the MySQL query.

Example:

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
$Biography = $_POST['Biography'];
$q = "
    update table 
    set Biography = '" . $Biography . "' 
    where UserID = " . $userid;
mysqli_query($link,$q);
```

I'm pretty stumped. The database is utf8, the connection is utf8, yet it's stripping special characters..

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Cheers,

**SOLVED:**  The form was loaded in via jQuery, and for some reason the page it was loading from had header tags. The lack of a meta charset tag messed up the character encoding in the actual form. Removing unnecessary header tags fixed the problem.

Comment: Did you try enforcing UTF8 via `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$mysql_connect_link)` (or just `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8')` for just this query) before your query?

Comment: What does $q look like before you execute it? (Use var_dump().) What happens if you use that same query directly--that is, without using php? Is your em dash a character (—), an html entity code (&mdash), or something else?

Comment: We're able to post the query via MySQL WorkBench and it works fine, the same query we get back from var_dump. I set the connection type for this query before we use it - it's not been an issue before, but I thought I'd try, to rule out the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The "database" character set is the default for new tables, and the "table" character set is the default for new columns. You need to ensure that the column is UTF8.

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html):

> The database character set and collation are used as default values
>   for table definitions if the table character set and collation are not
>   specified in CREATE TABLE statements. The database character set also
>   is used by LOAD DATA INFILE. The character set and collation have no
>   other purposes.

Comment: Thanks, the column is utf8_general_ci same as the table.